# Illegal invocation error using ES6 Proxy and node.js

Tags: node.js, es6-proxy

I can not figure out why the following code does not work:

```
var os = new Proxy(require('os'), {});
console.log( os.cpus() ); // TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

whereas

```
var os = require('os');
console.log(Reflect.apply(os.cpus, os, []));
```

or

```
var os = new Proxy(require('os'), {});
console.log( os.platform() );
```

works as expected.

Comment: Weirdly enough, `new Proxy(require('os').cpus, {})` works fine... I'm just as puzzled as you are.

Comment: I use the latest node.js (7.6.0) on Windows

Comment: Works now on node v10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having just skim read the source for the [`os` package](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/os.js) in the Node repo, it appears that the `cpus()` is exported from [`binding.getCPUs`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/efdc571a5804c8fd962e50edc0beb176f95cc092/src/node_os.cc) which is a C hook in the Node runtime environment.

`cpus()` therefore has the `binding` object as a function context, which is then lost through the proxy, giving you the `IllegalInvocation` error because there is no context to the function when you call it — although I'm hazy on the details.

`platform()` on the other hand is exported as `function () { return process.platform; }`, and hence it's just a function that returns an object, and doesn't need to be run under a specific context because Node function contexts will have the `process` variable specified by default (unless it has been overridden).

The following behaviour shows that applying the `os` as a context to the `cpus` function will work — proxies on function objects evidently lose the function context when calling properties.

```js
const os = require('os');
const proxy = new Proxy(os, {});  // proxy of object, functions called get proxy context rather than os context
const cpus = new Proxy(os.cpus, {});  // proxy of function, still has os context

console.log(os.cpus());  // works (duh)
console.log(cpus());     // works
console.log(proxy.cpus.apply(os, []));  // works
console.log(proxy.cpus());  // fails with IllegalInvocation
```

**Note:** If someone can clear up the details on the JS function context for an answer I'd love to read it too.

Comment: We finally get something more obscure than quantum mechanics !

Answer (score 3):

How about composition:

```
const os = require('os');
const proxy = new Proxy(os, {});
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(os).forEach(k => {
    var v = os[k];
    if(typeof v === "function") proxy[k] = v.bind(os);
});

//the `!!` because I don't want the actual print
//only a `true` or an `Error`
console.log(!!os.cpus());
console.log(!!proxy.cpus());
console.log(!!proxy.cpus.apply(proxy, []));
```

and all this as a utility function to "replace" `new Proxy()`, where `handler.bindTargetFunctions` can be

- either an array of keyNames to be bound (so you can be specific)
- or any truthy or falsy value to determine wether *all functions on the target* should be bound

the code:

```
function proxy(target, handler){
    const _proxy = new Proxy(target, handler);
    if(handler.bindTargetFunctions){
        let bindTargetFunctions = handler.bindTargetFunctions;
        if(!Array.isArray(bindTargetFunctions)){
            bindTargetFunctions = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target)
                .filter(key => typeof target[key] === "function");
        }
        bindTargetFunctions.forEach(key => {
            _proxy[key] = target[key].bind(target);
        });
    }
    return _proxy;
}

const os = proxy(require('os'), { bindTargetFunctions: true });
//or
//const os = proxy(require('os'), { bindTargetFunctions: ["cpus"] });

console.log(os.cpus());
```

**Edit:**

> Currently I try to bind functions directly in my get handler (see github.com/FranckFreiburger/module-invalidate/blob/master/…)‌​, the drawback of my solution is that each access to a function returns a new binding.

I entioned caching in the comments. This is how this cache could look like:

```
function createProxy(mod){
    var cache = Object.create(null);

    return new Proxy(function(){}, {
        get(target, property, receiver) {
            var val = Reflect.get(mod._exports, property, receiver);
            if(typeof val === "function"){
                if(!(property in cache) || cache[property].original !== val){
                    cache[property] = {
                        original: val,
                        bound: bal.bind(mod._exports)
                    }
                }
                val = cache[property].bound;
            }else if(property in cache){
                delete cache[property];
            }

            return val;
        }
    });
}
```

And No, I don't consider this cache a regular object. Not because it inherits from null, but because logically, to me this is a dictionary/map. And I don't know any reason why you would ever extend or proxy a particular dictionary.

Comment: Intresting !, Currently I try to bind functions directly in my `get` handler (see https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/module-invalidate/blob/master/index.js#L106), the drawback of my solution is that each access to a function returns a new binding.

Comment: Note also that with your solution, dynamically-added functions on the target will not be taken in account.

Comment: @FranckFreiburger, you could cache the bound functions, either by name in an object, or by src-function reference in an actual `Map`.

Comment: @FranckFreiburger And I rarely have any dynamically-added functions on my objects; I build the object once and leave the interface that way. Everything else invalidates the hidden class of that object and messes with the optimizer in modern JS-engines.

Comment: Ok but when you write this:
`module.exports.foo = function() {}`
`module.exports.bar = function() {}`
you are modifying the object and it is legitimate

Comment: @FranckFreiburger, yes it is legitimate *(and the code in my answer will deal with that properly)* but you don't extend an object later on, like `setTimeout(function(){ module.exports.asdf = someNewFunction; }, 10000);` or `var foo = require(whatever); foo.myUtility = anotherFunction;` This is considered a bad practice since PrototypeJS showed how bad you can mess up with extending foreign objects.

Comment: I fully understand your point of view but I have to deal js code that is not mine. Have a look at my project: https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/module-invalidate

Comment: @FranckFreiburger I've updated the answer regarding the mentioned caching. And I'll dive deeper into your repo; but later.