# How to determine that a JavaScript function is native (without testing '[native code]')

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, native

I would like to know if there is a way to differentiate a JavaScript script function (`function(){}`) from a JavaScript native function (like `Math.cos`).
I already know the `func.toString().indexOf('[native code]') != -1` trick but I was wondering if there is another way to detect it.

context:
I need to create a No-op forwarding ES6 Proxy that can handle native functions on an object but it fails with `TypeError: Illegal invocation` (see [Illegal invocation error using ES6 Proxy and node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496414/illegal-invocation-error-using-es6-proxy-and-node-js)).

To workaround this I `.bind()` all my functions in the `get` handler of my Proxy but if I could detect native function effectively, I will only need to `.bind()` these native functions.

more details: https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/module-invalidate/blob/master/index.js#L106

note:

```
(function() {}).toString() -> "function () {}"
(function() {}).prototype  -> {}

(require('os').cpus).toString() -> "function getCPUs() { [native code] }"
(require('os').cpus).prototype  -> getCPUs {}

(Math.cos).toString() -> "function cos() { [native code] }"
(Math.cos).prototype  -> undefined

(Promise.resolve().then).toString() -> "function then() { [native code] }"
(Promise.resolve().then).prototype  -> undefined
```

**edit:**
For the moment, the best solution is to test `!('prototype' in fun)` but it will not work with `require('os').cpus` ...

Comment: did you check this https://davidwalsh.name/detect-native-function ?

Comment: Why do you want another way?

Comment: @Tareq, detect-native-function uses fnToString and regexp that is similar to `func.toString().indexOf('[native code]') != -1`

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I need to create a No-op forwarding ES6 Proxy that can handle native functions on an object but this fails (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496414/illegal-invocation-error-using-es6-proxy-and-node-js).

Comment: It would be helpful to include that context in the question, so people don't suggest other methods with similar limitations.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated the question

Comment: Your "trick" does not work at all: `function f()  {return "[native code]";}` will result as if it were a built-in instead of a plain js function.

Comment: @Bakuriu, true, but it's far-fetched :)

Comment: Prototype checking in es6 is not stable
`func = () => {}; func.hasOwnProperty ('prototype') === false; `

Answer (score 16):

You could [`try`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) to use a [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor with the [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) value of the function. If it does not throw an error, then you get a custom function, otherwise you have a native function.

```js
function isNativeFn(fn) {
    try {
        void new Function(fn.toString());    
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function customFn() { var foo; }

console.log(isNativeFn(Math.cos));          // true
console.log(isNativeFn(customFn));          // false
console.log(isNativeFn(customFn.bind({}))); // true, because bind
```

Comment: it's the nature of a `try ... catch` block, but without `indexOf` or an regex, i see no different way, acutally.

Comment: check out `console.log(isNativeFn( customFn.bind( {/*whatever*/} ));`

Comment: *"The **`bind()`** method creates a new function"* and is obviously native.

Comment: True, but it does not throw `TypeError: Illegal invocation` when accessed through a ES6 Proxy

Comment: Your isNativeFn can be bypassed. 
I forge a function:

    `var a=(function(){}).bind(null);
    isNativeFn(a); //true`

Comment: @NinaScholz the `toString` also can be overriden, resulting an exception if you try to construct a function with that returned string from the overriden `toString`

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee right, but then you can not trust the language anymore.

Answer (score 8):

My summary on this topic: don't use it, it doesn't work. You can not certainly detect wether a function is native, because `Function#bind()` also creates "native" functions.

```js
function isSupposedlyNative(fn){
    return (/\{\s*\[native code\]\s*\}/).test(fn);
}

function foo(){ }
var whatever = {};

console.log("Math.cos():", isSupposedlyNative( Math.cos ));
console.log("foo():", isSupposedlyNative( foo ));
console.log("foo.bind():", isSupposedlyNative( foo.bind(whatever) ));
```

And since the Version by John-David Dalton, which Tareq linked to in this comment, does basically the same that code doesn't work either. I've checked it.

And the approach from Nina works on a similar principle, because again it is the `[native code]` part in the function body wich throws the error when trying to parse it into a new function.

The only secure way to determine wether the function you're dealing with is the native function, is to hold a reference to the native function and compare your function against that reference, but I guess this is no option for your use case.

Comment: I agree. Additionally, nowadays we have the Proxy API that makes it even harder to detect whether a function is monkey patched. 
The only "safe" way to do this check is to hold a reference of the “clean” native function and, later on, compare your potentially monkey patched function with it (which can be impractical). 
I added some more context here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73204287/4836602